# URL Rewrite not working with particular suffix

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm migrating my blog from LAMP/PHP to IIS. To preserve the URLs, I'm using the URL Rewrite Module. Out of 192 pages, this works on 191. Essentially I need to replace the "index.php" portion of the URL with a directory name and append an ".html" suffix.

My RegEx pattern:

```
^myblog/index\.php/(.+)
```

My rewrite URL:

```
myblog/contents/{R:1}.html
```

This works in most cases, rewriting

```
http://www.MYSITE/myblog/index.php/2013/04/29/goto_slides
```

to

```
http://www.MYSITE/myblog/contents/2013/04/29/goto_slides.html
```

However, it fails in one case:

```
http://www.MYSITE/myblog/index.php/2013/04/29/goto_notes_evolving_java
```

This returns 404, and the error page says the requested URL is:

```
http://MYSITE:80/myblog/contents/2013/04/29/goto_notes_evolving_java
```

(Note that the ".html" suffix was not added; adding that finds the page.)

The only difference I can see between URLs that work and the one that doesn't is the trailing "java".

How can I fix or work around this?

---

The web.config, per request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Rewrite blog URL from old PHP location" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^myblog/index\.php/(.+)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="myblog/contents/{R:1}.html" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post the exact rule (rules if more than one) you are using (copy/paste from the web.config)? Do you have any redirect/rewrite in your code? I don't see any reason why it would fail with the second url...

Comment: @cheesemacfly Done. And there's no code - these are very basic HTML/CSS pages with no redirects, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: I really don't see where this problem can come from. Can you try to remove the `<conditions>`? It shouldn't change anything but there are not used here so...Can you run the [Failed Request Tracing tool](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) and post the result somewhere on the internet to see if there is anything unusual (if you can log 2 requests: one working and the one that doesn't)?

Comment: @cheesemacfly "Failed request tracing is not enabled for this website" - and I don't have rights to change it (commercial hosting).

Comment: @cheesemacfly Removing the conditions **fixed it!** Thank you! Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: This is really weird...but if it works, so be it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the condition will fix your issue.
Your rule will become:

```
<rule name="Rewrite blog URL from old PHP location" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^myblog/index\.php/(.+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="myblog/contents/{R:1}.html" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```